# Choosing a button with a variable

Tags: objective-c

I have this working in C#, but don't know where to go with Objective C (Xcode specifically).

I have 8 buttons

Stack1, Stack2, etc.

I want to choose Stack(variable) and change the image.

In C# I used 
Button Stacks = this.Controls["Stack" + StackNumber.ToString()] as Button;
Stacks.BackgroundImage = .....

Can I do this in Objective C also?

Comment: you mean to say,that you need to put buttons programmatically and also to give name at the same time like above,right?

Comment: (I am new to Objective C programming) - I have created the buttons on storyboard, but want to change the images during the program's run. I want to change stack1's image when clicking on the stack7 button at one point, but change stack3's image when clicking on stack7 button later on.  I believe I could find a way around it, but I'd like to do it properly if a way exists.

Comment: Can you show me the image of the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand your question correctly. You want to change button's image by clicking on another button. You can assign `tag` property to your different buttons like `stack1.tag = 1001; , stack2.tag = 1002; , stack3.tag = 1003;`

Now in your button click method :

```
- (IBAction)buttonStack1Click:(id)sender // for stack1 button
{
   UIButton *tempStack = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:1003]; //to change image of stack3 button

   // Now change the image of stack3 button
   [tempStack setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"su.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Hope it gives an idea...

Answer (score 0):

Take help of for loop and implement the code below :

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[view addSubview:button];
```

Any query arises,you can tell me.. hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform certain function when a button is clicked then there are two ways..

One is Sarah way:Creating Button programmatically

The Other ways is if you are designing buttons in your interface builder :

Then :

1) **Make those Buttons an IBOutlet..Also Make IBAction**(Lots of tutorials available online..google them)

2) The **IBAction will be something** like this : `- (IBAction)StackButton(YourNumber)Clicked:(id)sender {`
In that function change the image of the button you want.

Like

```
[StackButton1 setImage:MyImage forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```